# Three blocks of code that do almost the same thing. How can I reduce these to the one block using 'this'?

Tags: jquery

I am a real novice when it comes to jQuery.  I don't really understand how to use 'this' correctly.  I have three blocks of code that do almost the same thing but for a different element.  I was wondering if it was possible to cut this code down using 'this'.  Here is my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    $(".shop-links1:contains('Tops')").click(function(){//Sort by tops
        $(".tops").show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
        $(".tunics").hide();
        $(".dresses").hide();
        $("#tabs ul li.a:not(:first)").animate
          ({height:'hide'}, 'slow') 
    });

    $(".shop-links1:contains('Tunics')").click(function(){//Sort by tunics
        $(".tops").hide();
        $(".tunics").show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
        $(".dresses").hide();
        $("#tabs ul li.a:not(:first)").animate
          ({height:'hide'}, 'slow') 
    });

    $(".shop-links1:contains('Dresses')").click(function(){//Sort by dresses
        $(".tops").hide();
        $(".tunics").hide();
        $(".dresses").show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
        $("#tabs ul li.a:not(:first)").animate
          ({height:'hide'}, 'slow') 
    });
```

Thanks

Chris

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you set up a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/christophson/8uYyG/1/

Comment: http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00448232/com601/assignment_1/login.html#

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at your HTML, you probably have something like this?

```
<a class="shop-links1">Tops</a>
<a class="shop-links1">Tunics</a>
<a class="shop-links1">Dresses</a>

<div class="tops">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>

<div class="tunics">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>

<div class="dresses">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I would add a class do your contents divs, call it "clothing-category", so you have this:

```
<div class="dresses clothing-category">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Sommething like this should probably work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".shop-links1").click(function(){
        $(".clothing-category").hide();
        // might need to lower-case the text here to get it to match
        $("#"+$(this).text()).show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
        $("#tabs ul li.a:not(:first)").animate
          ({height:'hide'}, 'slow') 
    });
});
```

If it doesn't work, change your links to have a separate attribute for the div ID they control, like so:

```
<a class="shop-links1" category="tops">Tops</a>
<a class="shop-links1" category="tunics">Tunics</a>
<a class="shop-links1" category="dresses">Dresses</a>
```

And then the suspect line of the click function would be this:

```
$("#"+$(this).attr('category')).show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
```

**Edit again:** Just noticed you're specifying class selectors for `tops`, `tunics` etc. and I typed up an id selector. If there's some reason you don't want id's on the elements for the different categories, it's easy to change to a class selector. Do this instead:

```
$("."+$(this).attr('category')).show().appendTo("#tabs-1");
// ^--- big difference here
```

**Edit:** I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with the `appendTo`. If the element is already in the DOM (which it has to be, somewhere, because you're not creating it in the script), then just calling `.show()` on it is enough to make it appear.  My understanding of [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is that you would end up duplicating a lot of elements in your dom, causing multiples of the same category to show. Is that what you want? If so, it seems very odd.

I would also need to see the markup you're using for the `#tabs` to figure out what the animate line is doing. I disclaim that because I'm not sure if this rewrite here will do the right thing withe the `ul` & `li` you're animating.

**Edit the 3rd:** I just tested this in the chrome dev console on your site after unbinding your click handler with this: `$(".shop-links1").unbind('click')`. This works just the same as the trio of click handlers you have:

```
$(".shop-links1").click(function(){
    $(".tops, .tunics, .dresses").hide();
    $("."+$(this).text().toLowerCase()).show();
    $("#tabs ul li.a:not(:first)").animate
      ({height:'hide'}, 'slow') 
});
```

I understand your tabs now, but the appendTo doesn't do what you think it does. It actually moves the items in the dom, adding them to the first tab after the `<section id="firstNineItems">` and removing them from the `<section id="secondNineItems">` (or whichever they're from) while leaving behind the empty `<section class="catalogListing">` tags. The way your markup & styles are set up, you don't need elements to be in the first tab to appear, even though it looks like the first tab is selected.

The hide animation works like you describe, but nothing gets the other tabs back onto the page. I guess you haven't wired the clear back up. Get that working and ask another question if you can't figure out how to get the pagination back, but it looks like it will probably work on your first swing at it.

Two other random points:

1. Is this a homework assignment? It's considered good form to mark your questions appropriately if that's the case, not only for the community but so whoever is evaluating your performance is clear you're not trying to take credit for others' work. (SO used to have a question tag for `homework` but I think it got voted into oblivion).
2. You have a lot of inline styles on the site. You'll probably save yourself time in the future if they were converted to css rules.

**Edit the last:** I trimmed down your fiddle and did away with the jquery-ui tab widget. I redid the tabs with some custom js, maybe 25 lines or so. The html structure required is way different, the `<section class="catalogListing">` and `<div="description">` pairs have been shrunk into just one section, there's no `<section class="first|second|thirdnineItems">` tags. The fiddle has way less bells and whistles, mainly so I wouldn't have to fight the display to get the pertinent parts to show up. The catalog listing section of the markup should be able to just drop in place, along with the javascript. You'll have to adapt the code to get the rest of the filters working (price ranges, sorts, artists, collections etc.). http://jsfiddle.net/8uYyG/3/

I realize this may not be what SO is *'for'*, but I had fun. In the future, I would really recommend doing a single-page app like this with a framework (like [Ember](http://emberjs.com/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) (my favorite)). Good luck.

Comment: This is the site: http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00448232/com601/assignment_1/login.html#

Comment: The shop links are located to the left.  Clicking tops appends the all tops into the first tab.  The same thing happens if you click dresses or tunics.  When one is click the others must be hidden.  The animate is just to make the tabs 2 and three disappear in cool ish way

Comment: It isn't an assignment, it is a practical that I tasked myself with to learn jQuery.  The inline will be removed later, i find it easier if they are in the one document until I get everything styled appropriately.  Your right the clear function no longer works because I edited a lot of the site.  I need to code it again but have not got that far.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time and help but I still cannot get it to work using the streamlined version of code you provided.  I don't understand the appendTo very well but if I do not use it the site doesn't function as intended.  At the moment it works 100% but my overall objective was to reduce the amount of code used.

Comment: What's not working? Did you remove the other click handlers? What's 'broken' in the old functions without the `appendTo`? Try adding that back onto the last click function I posted and see if that fixes it. Sorry to harp on the CSS, I guess I have known other devs to use that for prototyping, but it still makes me twitch from maintaining a web/desktop app-thing at my last job. Oh, and what browser are you using that it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I removed my code and replaced it with yours.  When i remove the append to the site does not filter the content.  For example at the moment if i click on the tops link to the left it will hide all other items and show just the tops within the first tab.  This is what i want it to do.  When i used you code, it hides everything

Comment: You code actually hides the tops and tunics and displays dresses fine.  But it does not do the same if the other links are chosen instead

Comment: I just realized that. The show/hide code I wrote works, but the tabs control is interfering with the category control. That's why it works with the `appendTo` call. The first tab is shown by default, so when you move the elements there, the tabs ui isn't hiding them anymore. You can see a similar interference with your old code. Go to the site, click the 2nd tab, then click the categories and suddenly everything is always hidden. I'm trying to think of a way to cleanly untangle them, but nothing is coming to mind which will work with straight jQuery.

Comment: Yeh i see what you mean.  Well i keep working at it sure.  Thanks for your help